Epson XP-6100 inkjet printer ignoring first sheet every time
I'm printing some photographs, individually, on A4 glossy paper.
Due to my experience with this printing device, I have to ensure there are two sheets of paper in the tray, as every single time I print, the first sheet rolls through with no attempt to print (the screen on the device says "Sheet 1" and the paper is drawn straight through at some speed), then the printer picks up the second sheet and starts to print my photograph (the screen on the device still says "Sheet 1").
I fail to see how I can add paper to a tray in a manner that is incorrect. I've tried with just the two pieces of paper, and adding the glossy sheets on top of the existing standard plain paper. No difference.
This is driving me mad — it is not an old printer — the Epson XP-6100, for those interested. Any suggestions?
Edits:

@hdhondt - I've just printed 3x single-page PDFs and they each spat out a single blank sheet followed by the print I expected. This in addition to the photography package I was using in my original posting.
Make and model are already included in original post
Print preview always shows a single page



Add info on the make and model of printer an OS. 2. Look to the printer settings. E.g., for HP, https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/First-page-of-a-document-fails-to-print/td-p/6412302


To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as screenshots and information on the printer or printing settings/configuration.

Does this happen from just one photo application (which one?), or from other apps as well?

What are the print settings? Does the Print Preview show two pages? Have you looked at the Epson support documentation and chosen the option "Skip Blank Pages" if it is present (https://files.support.epson.com/htmldocs/xp300_/xp300_ug/Source/Printers/Source/Troubleshooting/Reference/problem_blank_pages.html)?
